# lastpage.sty file not found, datime2.sty, indentfirst.sty, esint.sty not found

Tags: packages

> `lastpage.sty` file not found,  `datime2.sty` not found

- yesterday everything was working fine
- shut down macbook air
- reopened today and the files have shown an error
- the packages are installed
- i have reinstalled miktex and texmaker still the same error while compiling
- similarly `esint.sty` and `indentfirst` errors
- any help is welcome

Comment: It's better to update your `LaTeX` setup, hence these are common packages...

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using miktex on a MacBook air and not MacTeX?

Comment: well since i installed mik on my winpc idid the same on the mac --no particular reason than standardisation across the two platforms--any advantage of mak over mik

Comment: i found texmaker to be working well with miktex--any other better text editor to install with maktex

Comment: MacTeX has the advantage that it installs everything by default. MikTeX only installs a subset and relies on its install-on-the-fly feature for packages not already installed. Depending on the setup this install-on-the-fly may or may not word. It normally give you a popup asking if it should insall the package. But in some circumstances editors block this and you'll never notice unless you look through the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Below one probable cause and the remedy.

1. After fresh installation of texlive the directory 'lastpage' has been installed (I do not know why?) in '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/'. Invocation of 'texhash', quite obviously has lead to no improvement.
2. Next, I have copied the directory 'lastpage' from this location to correct location '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/', using administrator privileges (sudo or su for Linux).
3. Invocation of 'texhash' has completed the procedure.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: But the OP is not using TeX Live. And those are not the correct places for Macs anyway.